# iOS5 UITabBar change the color of the ...More navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, uitabbar, iphone-4

I'm trying to make my app feel more customized with a shaded navigation bar. For all controllers that I create, I can change the color of the navbar using:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

So all of my controllers use black navigation bars. However, when such controller is viewed in the "**...More**" tabbar section, **the tint reverts to blue**.

**How do I change the ...More navigation controller tint?**

As a side note, how do I would I go about globally define the style that my app is using?

edit:
To save some work, I defined a custom MyColors class, and put these methods in it:

```
+(UIColor*)navBarColor;
+(UIColor*)toolBarColor;
+(UIColor*)lightFontColor;
+(UIColor*)darkFontColor;
+(UIColor*)transparentColor;
```

This will help me change the colors of a UITabBar in the future without having to go hunting through each UIViewController and changing the color by hand!

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set a global color then use the new appearance proxy.

for example,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];
```

Any UIKit object that adopts the UIAppearence protocol can be set globally like this.

Answer (score 4):

`self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

Comment: +1 for including 'self.' took me a while to realise I need that!